# Conditions in undetermined coefficient method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just knew about the undetermined coefficient method for solving 2nd ODE:
$$y''(t) + p(t)y'(t) + q(t) = g(t)$$
and I was told that this method can only be applied when g(t) is a certain form- quasi-polynomial, I believed. So I want to ask why it only works with quasi-polynomial, and if possible what are the example and counter-example.

Comment: It only works with constants coefficients, and if the right side has an annihilating linear differential operator with constant coefficients. Similar goes if the left side is Euler-Cauchy, as this is equivalent to the constant-coefficient case.